# How to use router as rj45 female connector?

Tags: router

I want to connect two cables with rj45 pins using an old router.

The wan port of the router is not working.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Without more information, its hard to give specific advice.  However, with most modern router/firewall combos you can disable DHCP in its configuration page and simply use it as a switch.  This would allow you to connect the two computers.

Comment: Previously I had two computers and the internet cable connected to my router. But now the router's wan port is not working and so I would like to temporarily set up the connection such that I could forward the internet to one of my computer without shifting the other computer.

Answer (score 1):

Buy an ethernet switch instead - you can get a real cheapo for less then 10 bucks/quid/shekels

Google shopping 'gigabit switch' & sort by Price low to high.